# Retriving char in CString MFC

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I want to display every char in my CString. But this code makes my program crash. What am I doing wrong?

```
CString string;
string = "Text";

for(int i=0 ; i<string.GetLength() ; i++)
    AfxMessageBox(string.GetAt(i),NULL,MB_OK);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CString::GetAt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9d694ba1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) retrieves a character from the CString variable, you need to convert it to a string before you can display it in a MessaageBox, like:

```
CString string = "Text", ss;

for(int i = 0 ; i < string.GetLength() ; i++)
{   ss = string.GetAt(i);
    AfxMessageBox(ss,NULL,MB_OK);
}
```

Comment: Or simply `AfxMessageBox(string.Mid(i, 1), NULL, MB_OK);`.